# Observing sub categorical values in boxplot

Tags: r

For the iris data in R;

I want to observe the boxplot values only selecting one or multiple subcategories.

For example, when I run the command below, it displays all three subcategories;

```
boxplot(iris$Sepal.Length ~ iris$Species)
```

but when I want to narrow it to a single category or 2 categories I fail

```
boxplot(iris$Sepal.Length ~ iris[levels(iris$Species) == "setosa"])
```

How can I do this for a single subcategory or multiple categories which I want ?
Thank you

Comment: How about creating a new data frame with only these two species and then just use the first boxplot statement you used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We may use `with()`. To avoid empty plots of the species not selected we use `as.numeric()` to allow `boxplot()` to discriminate the species rather along their factor *levels* than their *labels*.

```
op <- par(mfrow=c(1, 2))
with(iris[iris$Species %in% "setosa", ],
     boxplot(Sepal.Length ~ as.numeric(Species), xlab="Species"))
mtext("setosa", 1, 1)

with(iris[iris$Species %in% c("setosa", "virginica"), ],
     boxplot(Sepal.Length ~ as.numeric(Species), xlab="Species", xaxt="n"))
mtext(c("setosa", "virginica"), 1, 1, at=1:2)
par(op)
```

#### Result

[image]